# TCP Server-Server communication

Tags: java, android, tcp

I'm developing an Android application (client) and want it to connect with my Java server using TCP communication, and so far everything is going well.

Server Code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import globalvariables.GlobalVariables;
import interface_package.ServerInterface;
import java.util.Timer;


/**
 *
 * @author wsserver
 */
public class ThreadedAndroidServer {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GlobalVariables.init();
        //Prevzemi staticen interface
        GlobalVariables.sinterface = new ServerInterface();
        GlobalVariables.sinterface.show();

        //INFINITE LOOP
        while(true)
        int port = GlobalVariables.portNo;

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server has started listening on port " + port);
            GlobalVariables.sinterface.setServerStatus("Server has started listening on port " + port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Cannot listen on port " + port + " : " + e);
            GlobalVariables.sinterface.setServerStatus("Error: Cannot listen on port " + port + " : " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        while (true) // infinite loop - loops once for each client
        {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); //waits here (forever) until a client connects
                System.out.println("Server has just accepted socket connection from a client");
                GlobalVariables.sinterface.setServerStatus("Server has just accepted socket connection from a client");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Accept failed: " + e);
                GlobalVariables.sinterface.setServerStatus("Accept failed: " + e);
                break;
            }

            // Create the Handle Connection object - our new thread object - only create it
            ThreadedHandleConnection con = new ThreadedHandleConnection(clientSocket);

            if (con == null) //If it failed send and error message
            {
                try {
                    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    os.writeObject("error: Cannot open socket thread");
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) //failed to even send an error message
                {
                    System.out.println("Cannot send error back to client: " + ex);
                    GlobalVariables.sinterface.setServerStatus("Cannot send error back to client: " + ex);
                }
            } else {
                con.start();
            } // otherwise we have not failed to create the HandleConnection object
            // start this thread now
        }

        try // do not get here at the moment 
        {
            System.out.println("Closing server socket.");
            GlobalVariables.sinterface.setServerStatus("Closing server socket.");
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not close server socket. " + e.getMessage());
            GlobalVariables.sinterface.setServerStatus("Could not close server socket. " + e.getMessage());
        }


    }
}
```

Connection Handler:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tcpServer_package;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import busimesslogic_package.Functions;

/**
 *
 * @author wsserver
 */
public class ThreadedHandleConnection extends Thread {

    private Socket clientSocket;            // Client socket object
    private ObjectInputStream is;           // Input stream
    private ObjectOutputStream os;          // Output stream

    // The constructor for the connecton handler
    public ThreadedHandleConnection(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    // The main thread execution method 
    public void run() {


        try {
            this.is = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            this.os = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            while (this.readCommand()) {
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Receive and process incoming command from client socket 
    private boolean readCommand() {
        String wholeCommand = null;

        try {
            wholeCommand = (String) is.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            wholeCommand = null;
        }
        if (wholeCommand == null) {
            this.closeSocket();
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Received: "+wholeCommand);
        //GET COMMAND PARAMETARS
        String[] commParams = wholeCommand.split(";");

        //GET COMMAND TYPE
        int type = Integer.parseInt(commParams[0]);

        //SELECT COMMAND PROCEDURE
        Functions functions = new Functions();
        String IPaddress = clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
        IPaddress = IPaddress.substring(IPaddress.indexOf("/")+1, IPaddress.indexOf(":"));

        switch (type) {
            case 1: {
                String sendText = getTextToSend();
                send(sendText);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                sendError("0;"+wholeCommand);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.gc();
        return true;
    }
    // Send a message back through to the client socket as an Object

    private void send(Object o) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sending " + o);
            this.os.writeObject(o);
            this.os.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Send a pre-formatted error message to the client 
    public void sendError(String msg) {
        this.send("error:" + msg);  //remember a string IS-A object!
    }

    // Close the client socket 
    public void closeSocket() //close the socket connection
    {
        try {
            this.os.close();
            this.is.close();
            this.clientSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Android Client Code:

```
package com.example.zpbitolaoperator;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import java.net.Socket;

import android.util.Log;

public class TCPClient{

    //Comunication variables
    private static Socket socket;
    private static ObjectOutputStream os;
    private static ObjectInputStream is;

    //Server parametars
    static String serverIP;
    static int port;

    //Communication status
    static boolean connectionStatus = false;

    public static boolean connectToServer() {
        try // open a new socket to port:  and create streams
        {

            serverIP = GlobalVariables.serverIP;
            port = GlobalVariables.portNo;

            socket = new Socket(serverIP, port);
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Connected to Server");
            connectionStatus = true;
            return true;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Failed to Connect to Server " +ex.toString(), ex.getCause());
            connectionStatus = false;
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static boolean closeConnection(String message){
        try{
            socket.close();
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Closed connection to Server");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Failed to close connection to Server " +ex.toString(), ex.getCause());
            return false;
        }

    }
    private static String sendMessage(String message) {
        String returnString;
        send(message);
        returnString = (String) receive();
        if (returnString != null) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Server returned: " + returnString);
        }else{
            return returnString = "ERROR";
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    // method to send a generic object.
    private static void send(Object o) {
        try {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Sending: " + o);
            os.writeObject(o);
            os.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Sending to server " +ex.toString(), ex.getCause());
        }
    }

    // method to receive a generic object.
    private static Object receive() {
        Object o = null;
        try {
            o = is.readObject();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Receive from server " +ex.toString(), ex.getCause());
        }
        return o;
    }
    /**
     * Isprakja poraka do server
     * @param message
     * @return ili ERROR ili poraka
     */
    public synchronized static String sendToServer(String message) {

        String rez = "";
        try {
            rez = sendMessage(message);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Send to server " +ex.toString(), ex.getCause());
        }
        return rez;
    }

    public static boolean getCommunicationStatus(){
        return connectionStatus;
    }
}
```

I am sending String data to my server (comand;param1;param2....), the server proces that data and returns some data do the android application. The android application is the TCP Client and the java application is the server. For every connection the server creates thread (infinite) that handles that connection. The problem is that my server cant send something without the client sending the request first. The ObjectInputStream readObject() blocks the thread until the client send some data. I want to use the same socket to send in the other direction (java -> android and the android application send some data back) .I know that this can be done by opening another socket where the Android will be the server and the java application will be the client. Is this posible and how?

Comment: You should be able to set a timeout on the socket on the server to force it to continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to concurrently receive data from a client *and* send data to the client then you'll have to either use two threads per client (one to receive and one to send) or use [non-blocking IO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O).